# How to set values passed from python list to a html progress bar

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have an application where people can read news items and comment.Then those comments are analysed using NLP techniques and comments are classified in to two categories as positive, negative. What I want to do is display how much percentage  of comments are positive and how much percentage  of comments are negative under each news item.So what I did was I added the  [id, headline, newsText, date , positiveCommentPercentage, negativeCommentPercentage] data of each news item in to a Python list and appended it in to a another List and passed it to the web page.

```
 list = [id, headline, newsText, date ,positiveCommentPercentage ,negativeCommentPercentage ]
    newsData.append(list)

template = 'AppOne/news.html'
return render(request, template, {'nd': newsData})
```

I could successfully display the news headline,news and date on the web page as follows,

```
<div>
{% for x in nd %}
    <h2>{{x.1}}</h2>
    <h5>{{x.2}}</h5>
    <h6>{{x.3}}</h6>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

But I want to show the number of "positive comments percentage" and "number of negative comments percentage" under each news item as 2 progress bars as shown in the image
[image: positive comments percentage and negative comments percentage shown on the progress bar]

So I tried to use the html progress bars shown in 'w3schools' site.

```
    <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round">
<div class="w3-container w3-blue w3-round" style="width:60%">60%</div>
```

The question I have is how to set the positiveCommentPercentage ,negativeCommentPercentage values passed from python list, to the style width attribute of the div.

I'm using Django framework  here.So please help me to do that or suggest a new way to that using any easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never encountered that interpolation style. I am going to look it up... But if it works for the headline, text and date, am sure it would work for the sentiment percentage too. For positive comment, inside your loop, something like:

`<div class="w3-container w3-blue w3-round" style="width:{{x.4}}%">{{x.4}}%</div>`